# How to export a *.p7b cert from *.pfx file

Tags: windows-phone-8, certificate, pkcs#7

MSDN said:
X509Certificate.Export
The contentType parameter accepts only the following values of the X509ContentType enumeration: Cert, SerializedCert, and Pkcs12. Passing any other value causes a CryptographicException to be thrown.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxz81eb9(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxz81eb9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Is there any other methods?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I understand what .p7b format is.

```
static void ExportCert()
{
        X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(@"E:\SimonSelf.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        X509Certificate2Collection x509List = new X509Certificate2Collection(x509);
        byte[] p7bBinary = x509List.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs7);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\SimonSelf.p7b", FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(p7bBinary, 0, p7bBinary.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }
}
```